# Заполнение массива

Tags: java

Мне нужно сделать массив `a`, где данные будут браться из компонента `textField`. Как это сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: То что вы написали - бессмыслица. Вопрос бессвязный и пример кода - полная чушь. Пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос нормально. И разберитесь с позорным примером кода.

Comment: Будуд) лол.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a [] = testField.getText().toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`int getChars (char [ ] data)` копирует текст в символьный массив данных;